# Counting the number of p-tags (<p>) in a website from a user's choice of link input in Python 3

Tags: python, html, counter

> Write a program that asks the user for a URL. It should then retrieve
>   the contents of the page at that URL and print how many `<p>` tags are
>   on that page. Your program should just print an integer.

Here's my code:

```
import urllib.request

link = input('Enter URL: ')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
html = response.read()
counter = 0
for '<p>' in html:
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
```

However, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "python", line 16

SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

What would be the better method to execute this code? Should I use the `find` method instead?

Comment: `counter = html.count('<p>')`

Comment: `for '<p>' in html:` doesn't make sense in Python syntax - you can't have a literal as a loop variable, think more `for x in y:`. You should use an HTML parser, like Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `response.read()` returns bytes; hence you need  to cast it to string:

`html = str(response.read())`

then, no need for `for` loop, you can just use `count = html.counter('<p>')`

Hope it help.s

Answer (score 1):

Try to use BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = input('Enter URL: ')
response = requests.get(link)
html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tags = soup.findAll('p')

print(len(tags))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works good:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get(input('Enter URL: '))
root = html.fromstring(page.content)
print(len(root.xpath('//p')))
```